# String Allocated with malloc Enaccessible after Function Return

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have run into a strange bug and I cannot for the life of me get it figured out. I have a function that decodes a byte array into a string based on another encoding function. The function that decodes looks roughly like this:

```
char *decode_string( uint8_t *encoded_string, uint32_t length,
    uint8_t encoding_bits ) {
        char *sequence_string;
        uint32_t idx = 0;
        uint32_t posn_in_buffer;
        uint32_t posn_in_cell;
        uint32_t encoded_nucleotide;
        uint32_t bit_mask;

        // Useful Constants
        const uint8_t CELL_SIZE = 8;
        const uint8_t NUCL_PER_CELL = CELL_SIZE / encoding_bits;

        sequence_string = malloc( sizeof(char) * (length + 1) );
        if ( !sequence_string ) {
            ERR_PRINT("could not allocate enough space to decode the string\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        // Iterate over the buffer, converting one nucleotide at a time.
        while ( idx < length ) {
            posn_in_buffer = idx / NUCL_PER_CELL;
            posn_in_cell = idx % NUCL_PER_CELL;
            encoded_nucleotide = encoded_string[posn_in_buffer];
            encoded_nucleotide >>= (CELL_SIZE - encoding_bits*(posn_in_cell+1));
            bit_mask = (1 << encoding_bits) - 1;
            encoded_nucleotide &= bit_mask;
            sequence_string[idx] = decode_nucleotide( encoded_nucleotide );
                // decode_nucleotide returns a char on integer input.
            idx++;
        }
        sequence_string[idx] = '\0';
        printf("%s", sequence_string);    // prints the correct string
        return sequence_string;
}
```

The bug is that the return pointer, if I try to print it, causes a segmentation fault. But calling `printf("%s\n", sequence_string)` inside of the function will print everything just fine. If I call the function like this:

```
const char *seq = "AA";
uint8_t *encoded_seq;
encode_string( &encoded_seq, seq, 2, 2);
char *decoded_seq = decode_string( encoded_seq, 2, 2);

if ( decoded_seq ) {
    printf("%s\n",decoded_seq);    // this crashes
    if ( !strcmp(decoded_seq, seq) ) {
        printf("Success!");
}
```

then it will crash on the print. 
A few notes, the other functions seem to all work, I've tested them fairly thoroughly (i.e. `decode_nucleotide`, `encode_string`). The string also prints correctly inside the function. It is only after the function returns that it stops working.
My question is, what might cause this memory to become invalid just by returning the pointer from a function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will add it in. The part that is bizarre though, is that it seems to be doing everything correctly. The decoded string is correct and null terminated (i.e. if the initial string is "AA" and I encode it, then decode it, it gives me "AA", as long as I print it inside the function.

Comment: why is there an extra parameter passed to `printf` ? also are you actually checking if `my_decoded_sequence` is NULL or not ? can you put a fully testable [mcve] ? i.e. show the code *outside* that's actually doing the printing.

Comment: My wag is it has nothing to do with this function per se, which you can show by stubbing it with a function which mallocs & inits a length-character string.   I believe an earlier function has trashed the stack, or decode_nucleotide is trashing the stack, and some previously set and future relied upon register is causing your fault.   May I ask what the role of “2” is in the printf() ?

Comment: Please learn how to use gdb. It helps.

Comment: @mevets I think you may be right. I will have to try to just step back through as much of it as I can. Unfortunately I can't share much of the code at the moment.

Comment: @grimey I’ll go one further -- encode_string() is the culprit;  It is using its first argument as a place to store the encoding without assigning it to an allocated buffer, thus the encoding is corrupting the stack.  I prefer small, unmarked bills.

Comment: Seemingly irrational crashes around dynamically allocated memory are a strong evidence that the program's memory management got corrupted. This might have happened way before the actual crash occurs (or not). To test for proper memory access use a memory checker like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Answer (score 0):

First (and not that important, but) in the statement:

```
sequence_string = malloc( sizeof(char) * (length + 1) );
```

`sizeof(char)` by definition is always == `1`. so the statement becomes:

```
sequence_string = malloc(length + 1);
```

In this section of your post:

```
char *decoded_seq = decode_string( encoded_seq, 2, 2);
```

...since I cannot see your implementation of `decode_string`, I can only make assumptions about how you are verifying its output before returning it.  I do however understand that you are expecting the return value to contain values that would be legal contents for a C string.  I can also *assume* that because you are working with coding and decoding, that the output type is likely `unsigned char`.  If I am correct, then a legal range of characters for an output type of *[unsigned char is 0-255](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)*.

You are not checking the output before sending the value to the `printf` statement. If the value at the memory address of `decoded_seq` happens to be `0`, (in the range of `unsigned char`) your program would crash.  String functions do not work well with null pointers.

You should verify the return of _decode_string_ sending it to `printf`

```
char *decoded_seq = decode_string( encoded_seq, 2, 2);
if(decoded_seq != NULL)
{
    ...
```

Comment: I believe that there should be memory allocated there. It is allocated within the function call to `decode_string`, which then returns the pointer. So the value of `decoded_seq` should be a pointer to the allocated memory with, in theory, the string that was decoded.

Comment: @Grimey - Agreed, I see where you have created the memory.  But I have re-done the content of this answer, focusing instead on the importance of checking the return value of `decode_string` before using it.